# Multiple RHEL local development VMs?

Tags: rhel, development, vagrant

The company I work for is likely going to migrate our servers to Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL).

In the past I have been responsible for setting up our development boxes using Vagrant to replicate our production OSs.

Which type of subscription will to allow us to run multiple virtual machines per developer? (this is unclear to me, after reading the Red Hat documentation)

We have multiple developers and multiple projects. Each project is running in a separate VM. Again, these are not production boxes, and only need to communicate with the developers machine running the guest RHEL environment. We do not have the option of running a similar OS - e.g. CentOS - as we need the production and development environments to match exactly.

Comment: You should ask your account manager. If you’re able to reduce the requirement to one VM per developer, the no-cost developer subscription might work, but I take it that’s not what you’re after.

Comment: Actually, the number of VMs is not limited with the no-cost developer subscription. But it's generally not very well suited for corporate use. See [no-cost RHEL FAQ](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/frequently-asked-questions-no-cost-red-hat-enterprise-linux-developer-subscription/).

Answer (score 0):

You can choose from both paid and no-cost subscription options.

Paid:

- [Red Hat Enterprise Linux Developer Suite](https://www.redhat.com/en/store/red-hat-enterprise-linux-developer-suite#?sku=RH2262474) (no support)
- [Red Hat Enterprise Linux Developer Workstation](https://www.redhat.com/en/store/red-hat-enterprise-linux-developer-workstation#?sku=RH3482727) (single subscriptions)
- [Red Hat Enterprise Linux Developer Support](https://www.redhat.com/en/store/red-hat-enterprise-linux-developer-support#?sku=RH2282403) (25 subs.)

No cost: [developers.redhat.com](https://developers.redhat.com/) (rather inconvenient for corporate purposes because every one of your developers would need to create an account, renew it every year, etc. -- the paid options all allow for having an arbitrary number of subscriptions managed using a single account; see [no-cost FAQ](https://developers.redhat.com/articles/frequently-asked-questions-no-cost-red-hat-enterprise-linux-developer-subscription/)).